# I can only erase grease pencil with Huion tablet

Tags: interface, customization, grease-pencil

Blender 2.78c

Graphic tablet: Huion 640p

Whenever I try to click in the workspace, a red dotted circle appears (in every mode). I found it is eraser. In UI, the tablet works completely fine. Also using the mouse everything is OK. 
But when i mapped the left mouse button to the pen button, it also makes that circle.

I can't find how to fix that.

Comment: Try change Tablet API in Preferences (in Input section)